# Failed /SetEncTypeAttr : 0xc0000034

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, entra-id

I want to set encryption type attribute for the domain
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh240207(v=ws.11).aspx

When i run in Windows Server 2012 R2,

```
ksetup /SetEncTypeAttr EXAMPLE.COM AES128-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96
```

I am getting below error,

```
Setting enctypes for domain EXAMPLE.COM to:AES128-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96
Setting enctypes on EXAMPLE.COM failed with 0xc0000034
Failed /SetEncTypeAttr : 0xc0000034
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Might be I am too late for reply.

```
ksetup /SetEncTypeAttr EXAMPLE.COM AES128-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96
```

Here, EXAMPLE.COM should be replaced with FQDN.

```
ksetup /SetEncTypeAttr FQDN>EXAMPLE.COM AES128-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96
```

Will work..!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ksetup /SetEncTypeAttr` only to set the encryption types for the trust relationship to a *trusted* domain, not for your domain itself. See my Q&A [here](https://serverfault.com/q/1099053/536173).